# 7z with encryption: System ERROR: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: windows, encryption, zip, 7-zip

Doing

```
7z a test.zip test.txt -mem=AES256 -pPassword
```

works and create an encrypted ZIP archive. But:

```
7z a test.7z test.txt -mem=AES256 -pPassword
```

fails on Windows with:

> System ERROR:
> The parameter is incorrect.

Adding the parameter `-t=7z` or `-t7z` did not change anything.

**How to create an AES256-encrypted 7z archive from command line?**

Note: If I remove `-mem=AES256`, it works, but I'm not sure which encryption method is used.

Comment: The `-mem=AES256` switch only applies to the [Zip archive format type](https://documentation.help/7-Zip/method.htm).  The 7z archive format type uses AES-256 encryption [by deault](https://www.7-zip.org/7z.html), often referred to as `7zAES`.  When listing the technical info for test.7z --using `7z l -slt test.7z` -- you'll see `7zAES` listed, followed by a colon and a number (N) -- which means [2^N SHA-256 iterations](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/b66bceb9/#dcdd).

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been given in a comment (thus the community wiki answer):

The `-mem=AES256` switch only applies to the [Zip archive format type](https://documentation.help/7-Zip/method.htm).

The 7z archive format type uses AES-256 encryption [by default](https://www.7-zip.org/7z.html), often referred to as 7zAES. When listing the technical info for test.7z - using `7z l -slt test.7z` - you'll see `7zAES` listed, followed by a colon and a number (N) -- which means [2^N SHA-256 iterations](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/b66bceb9/#dcdd).